# Resizing a UITableView within a UISplitView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have programmatically instantiated a UISplitView with a LeftViewController and a RightViewController (Master/Detail).

I've been trying to modify the UITableView's (LeftViewController) width without success. Is this even possible within a UISplitView?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can assume you are trying to change the width of the masterViewController of the SplitViewController.

The width of the SplitViewController controllers is fixed and you can not change it.
You can small or expand the table view itself but the view controller will not be affected from that.

Look here, that might help you create your own SplitViewController -
[MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/)

Or here -
[custom uisplitviewcontroller](http://www.mindtreatstudios.com/our-projects/custom-uisplitviewcontroller-ios/)